# Confusing automatic dereferencing of Arc

Tags: rust

This is an example taken from the [`Mutex` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html):

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::thread;

const N: usize = 10;
fn main() {
    let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    let (tx,rx) = channel();
    for _ in 0..N{
        let (data, tx) = (data.clone(), tx.clone());
        thread::spawn(move || {
            // snippet
        });
    }
    rx.recv().unwrap();
}
```

My question is where the `snippet` comment is. It is given as

```
let mut data = data.lock().unwrap();
*data += 1;
if *data == N {
    tx.send(()).unwrap();
}
```

The type of data is `Arc<Mutex<usize>>`, so when calling `data.lock()`, I assumed that the `Arc` is being automatically dereferenced and an `usize` is assigned to `data`. Why do we need a `*`in front of `data` again to dereference it?

The following code which first dereferences the `Arc` and then proceeds with just an `usize` also works in place of the snippet.

```
let mut data = *data.lock().unwrap();
data += 1;
if data == N {
    tx.send(()).unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Follow the docs.  Starting with [`Arc<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html):

- Does `Arc::lock` exist?  No.  Check `Deref`.
- `Deref::Target` is `T`.  Check [`Mutex<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html).
- Does `Mutex::lock` exist?  [Yes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.lock).  It returns `LockResult<MutexGuard<T>>`.
- Where does `unwrap` come from?  [`LockResult<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/type.LockResult.html) is a synonym for `Result<T, PoisonError<T>>`.  So it's `Result::unwrap`, which results in a `MutexGuard<T>`.
- Therefore, `data` is of type `MutexGuard<usize>`.

So this is wrong:

> so when calling `data.lock()`, I assumed that the `Arc` is being automatically dereferenced and an `usize` is assigned to `data`.

Thus the question is not why you can't assign directly, but how you're able to assign an `usize` value *at all*.  Again, follow the docs:

- `data` is a `MutexGuard<usize>`, so check [`MutexGuard<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html).
- `*data` is a pointer dereference in a context that requires mutation.  Look for an implementation of `DerefMut`.
- It says that for `MutexGuard<T>`, it implements `DerefMut::deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T`.
- Thus, the result of `*data` is `&mut usize`.

Then we have your modified example.  At this point, it should be clear that this is *not at all* doing the same thing: it's mutating a local variable that happens to contain the same value as the mutex.  But because it's a local variable, changing it has absolutely no bearing on the contents of the mutex.

---

Thus, the short version is: the result of locking a mutex is a "smart pointer" wrapping the actual value, not the value itself.  Thus you have to dereference it to access the value.

Comment: I prefer your answer. I guess the only thing you didn't address was the fact that `data` is two different types in the snippets provided. The first one is the `MutexGuard<T>`, the second is just an integral variable.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Aah, right.  Didn't even see that.

Comment: @DK Thank you for the explanation. Now it makes sense.