# Borrowing from a struct in Rust

Tags: rust, mutex, smart-pointers

Hello Rust Developers,

I have continually run into an issue in rust which prevents me from writing programs that use structs.The issue I run into is the inability to access struct variables inside of the implementation for that struct. For example in the image attached I have a struct named Bank which has a vector of account numbers. I am able to access a reference to that accounts field; however, when I attempt to dereference it so that I can check if a value is contained in the accounts vector, I get the following compiler error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of dereference of `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, std::vec::Vec<i32>>`
  --> src/main.rs:24:24
   |
24 |         let accounts = *accounts_ref;
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                        |
   |                        move occurs because value has type `std::vec::Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                        help: consider borrowing here: `&*accounts_ref`
```

Has anyone overcome this obstacle before? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have continually gotten stuck on variations of this in several applications.

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Bank {
    accounts: Arc<Mutex<Vec<i32>>>,
}

impl Bank {
    fn new(n: usize) -> Self {
        let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(n);
        for _ in 0..n {
            v.push(0);
        }
        Bank {
            accounts: Arc::new(Mutex::new(v)),
        }
    }

    fn transfer(&self, from: usize, to: usize, amount: i32) -> Result<(), ()> {
        let accounts_mutex = self.accounts.clone();
        let accounts_ref = accounts_mutex.lock().unwrap();

        let accounts = *accounts_ref;

        return Ok(());
    }
}
```

Comment: When accessing data that is in a Mutex, you generally don't need to dereference it explicitly. You can mostly call methods on the `MutexGuard` as if it was the inner data.

Comment: For example, you can call methods like `accounts_ref.len()` or `accounts_ref.iter()`, to which will actually call the methods on the vector.

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning that you don't need to clone the `Arc` inside `transfer`. You would clone the Arc only if you need to share it. For example if you had two instances of `Bank` but you wanted both to have access to the same accounts data.

Comment: Thank you @PeterHall, that seemed to resolve my issue. Do you know of a way I could dereference it explicitly if I needed to? Or does rust prohibit that?

Comment: Dereferencing would mean _moving_ the value out of the mutex. If it was allowed, it would leave the mutex with a dangling pointer. If you want to own the data, you can clone it. Otherwise, you can do anything _to_ the data by accessing it through the `MutexGuard`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46314582/493729, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56624004/493729

Comment: Thank you @PeterHall, you have been very helpful in answering my questions!

Comment: Note that you _can_ move the value out of the mutex with [`into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.into_inner), but this destroys the mutex itself (so you need to first move the mutex out of the `Arc` with [`try_unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.try_unwrap)).